# Adobe LiveCycle Print to Envelope

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, livecycle

I created a PDF form usuing Adobe LiveCycle 8.2. The form captures data, after this data is validated (Customer Name, Address, Account Number etc)
the usuer prints it, that gets mailed to the customer, printing the detailed report no problem, the problem im having is im trying to figure out a way that after the report is printed an enveloped needs to be printed as well with the info entered in the form.
Any one have an idea how to approach/tackle this issue?
Adobe LC has JavaScript and FormCal to extend  LiveCycle limitations

flow:
User inputs info into PDF.
user prints PDF.
user copies cust name and address to word doc to print the envelope.
printed PDF and Envelope are mailed to cust.
problem:
How to print the cust name and address directly to envelope from the PDF without going to word just to print the envelope. Id like the PDF to print the report and the envelope, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please help me here , i am stuck here and its urgent now [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960808/expression-or-reg-ex-for-java-script-or-adobe-livecycle-tools

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle printing an envelope using the data from your LiveCycle form is to add a separate envelope page to your original form. Then add a separate print button that will print only this envelope page. Here are some basic steps on how to accomplish this using LiveCycle Designer:

1) Create a new Master Page in your original form document. This Master Page should have the same dimensions as the envelope you wish to print on.

2) Create a new Page to your form document that uses the envelope Master Page template. In this page add the form fields you wish to print onto your envelope (name, address, city, state, ZIP, etc.) and place them in the proper location for your envelope layout.

3) Bind the envelope field values to their related field values on your original form.

4) Set presence value on your Envelope page to "hidden"

5) Add a new button to your original form page called "Print Envelope"

6) Add JavaScript to the "Print Envelope" button that performs the following functions:

- Set original form pages presence to "hidden"
- Set envelope page presence to "visible"
- Print document

7) Add a "postPrint" event for each of your original form pages that will set the page presence property to "visible". Add a "postPrint" event for your envelop page that will set that page presence to "hidden".